# Plotting a graph in xpages using data stored in a document

Tags: javascript, xpages, dojox.charting

I am working with xpages and I need to present data points on a graph. I need to be able to select a document which I need to plot (I tried doing that by storing data points in a view). I tried to use javascript to define my plot but I can't get it to plot a file/document with data. It doesn't work unless I hard code all the data points. Is there something I am missing? Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried so far? you need to add more details to your question in order to get usable answers. For now maybe this can help: http://blog.wilhow.net/2013/03/17/charting-104-in-xpages-connecting-to-notes-document/

Comment: Adding some code snippet would help in identifying your problem.

Comment: The link you sent is perfect actually, I'll give that a go. So far I managed to hard code the data for the graph in a script library (javascript) and connect it to a button which you can click to view the graph which has been hard coded. I wanted to find a way of plotting that graph using the same data but instead of hard coding it I wanted to select a filed/ocument which contains that data so I can plot it. I tried to store that data in a view but couldn't find a way of getting that data from the view to plot.

Comment: Code samples and more detailed explanation what you tried are essential

Answer (score 1):

Iona, 
depending on your plot library (I like [d3js](http://www.d3js.org/)), you will find JavaScript methods that allow you to retrieve those values using an Ajax call to an URL. That is the first step you need to sort out (with a static JSON file on your Domino).

Once you have that working, then you replace the static JSON file with the Ajax/Json control from the extension library that delivers values based on a script you write. There you can read a view, get values from a document or whatever fits your needs.